# I wrote a Conversation with python-telegram-bot but multiple user cant interact with bot at the same time

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

This conversation works good but waits working time end with one user then awnser other users, I tried to find a way for this conversation to interact with multiple users at the same time but I couldn't find, How can I fix this solve this issue?

```
from telegram import Update, ReplyKeyboardRemove
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext, ConversationHandler
from datetime import datetime

GET_START_DATE, GET_END_DATE, CALCULATE = map(chr, range(3))
END = ConversationHandler.END


def get_start_date(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    update.message.reply_text(
        '\U0001F4C5 start date')
    update.message.reply_text(
        '\U00002705 Example :10-04-2022')
    return GET_START_DATE


def get_end_date(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    context.user_data['start_date'] = update.message.text
    update.message.reply_text(
        '\U0001F4C5 end date :')
    update.message.reply_text(
        '\U00002705 Example :20-04-2022')
    return GET_END_DATE


def get_file(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    context.user_data['end_date'] = update.message.text
    days = (datetime.strptime(context.user_data['end_date'], "%Y-%m-%d") - datetime.strptime(
        context.user_data['start_date'], "%Y-%m-%d")).days
    if days <= 125:
        update.message.reply_text(
            '\U0001F4C1 upload file plz')
        return CALCULATE
    else:
        update.message.reply_text(
            '\U0000274C too long days')
        update.message.reply_text(
            ' \U000021A9 again test /command')
        return ConversationHandler.END


def calculate(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    try:
        # calculate something here
        return ConversationHandler.END
    except:
        update.message.reply_text(
            '\U0000274C something wrong try again /command ')
        return ConversationHandler.END


def cancel(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    update.message.reply_text(
        'Bye', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    )
    return ConversationHandler.END


def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater("TOKEN_BOT_TEST")
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    conv_handler_test = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('test', get_start_date)],
        states={
            GET_START_DATE: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, get_end_date)],
            GET_END_DATE: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, get_file)],
            CALCULATE: [MessageHandler(Filters.document, calculate)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
        map_to_parent={
            END: END,
        },
    )
    dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler_test)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

as my code i check all of examples in python-telegram-bot github but i didnt understand how fix this issue

Comment: when someone runs a command \test and starts, this bot didn't answer other user until that conversation end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow your bot to answer multiple users at same time you have to pass `run_async=True` in your conversation handler like:

```
conv_handler_test = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('test', get_start_date)],
        states={
            GET_START_DATE: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, get_end_date)],
            GET_END_DATE: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, get_file)],
            CALCULATE: [MessageHandler(Filters.document, calculate)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
        map_to_parent={
            END: END,
        },
run_async=True
    )
```

This will make your conversation handler run asynchronously allowing multiple users to interact at same time.

If `run_async` is set to True, you should not pass a handler instance, that needs to be run synchronously in another context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Handler.block`

```
application.add_handler(
  MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, echo, block=False) 
)
```

or `Application.concurrent_updates`

```
Application.builder().token('TOKEN').concurrent_updates(True).build()
```

[they described it more here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Concurrency)